# A Shortcode Within a Shortcode, Nested shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, download, shortcode

**Problem**

I have a plugin called [WP-Filebase](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-filebase/) (see [also here](http://wpfilebase.com/)) that allows a user to upload media. It has a shortcode to allow the user to publish a download link for that media.

The shortcode the user would insert into the post is this:

```
[wpfilebase tag=file path='EXAMPLE.JPG' tpl=download-button /]
```

**Goal**

Replace **EXAMPLE.JPG** with this shortcode below:

```
 function get_title( ){
   return get_the_title(); 
   }

add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'get_title' );
```

to make the two short codes look like this essentially:

```
[wpfilebase tag=file path='[page_title]' tpl=download-button /]
```

**WHY?**

Because the name of the uploaded media (in my case it's images because it's a wallpaper site) matches the name of the post title.

So if I can enable the second short code to execute within the first short code, I don't have to manually replace EXAMPLE.JPG on my own with a 500+ posts, the short code can do that for me automatically.

Comment: It looks like you can [create a template](http://wpfilebase.com/documentation/templates/) and then use PHP code to send in a placeholder. If this is the case, just use the PHP WP function to get the title, and you should be able to do this.

Comment: That seems like a good start. I will continue to read on there but I have no knowledge of coding, especially not php. Basic html and css stuff sadly.

Comment: Why don't you define a new shortcode that does what you want: add_shortcode( 'wpfilebase_specialized', function(){ echo do_shortcode( '[wpfilebase tag=file path="' . get_the_title() . '" tpl=download-button ]' ); } );

Comment: I am stupid - please replace echo with return - add_shortcode( 'wpfilebase_specialized', function(){ return do_shortcode( '[wpfilebase tag=file path="' . get_the_title() . '" tpl=download-button ]' ); } );

Comment: Neither of the two work sadly, I just tried ;(

Comment: I found something that you can probably use as a reference though maybe http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100100/nested-shortcodes . And as for the above two codes, the post doesn't output any texts, so it means that the code is working the php portion I guess, but no download link either so it's not doing it correctly?

Comment: HERE is the code behind the download button that's triggered with that first [wp file base] short code I believe `<div style="text-align:center; width:250px; margin: auto; font-size:smaller;"><a href="%file_url%" class="wpfb-dlbtn"><div></div></a>
%file_display_name% (%file_size%, %file_hits% downloads)
</div>`

Comment: In the two codes Magenta Carta posted, he missed the .JPG after the get_the_title and missed the slash "/" before the last bracket. And still doesn't work. Maybe I missed something. `add_shortcode( 'wpfilebase_specialized', function(){ return do_shortcode( '[wpfilebase tag=file path="' . get_the_title() . '".JPG tpl=download-button /]' ); } );`

Comment: MAGENTA CARTA - YOU SIR ARE A HERO !!

Comment: BOTH CODES WORK FINAL VERSION TO BOTH CODES 

`add_shortcode( 'wpfilebase_specialized2', function(){ echo do_shortcode( '[wpfilebase tag=file path="' . get_the_title() . '.JPG" tpl=download-button /]' ); } );

add_shortcode( 'wpfilebase_specialized', function(){ return do_shortcode( '[wpfilebase tag=file path="' . get_the_title() . '.JPG" tpl=download-button /]' ); } );`

Comment: SOLVED! FEEL FREE TO LOCK IT!

Comment: How do I give rep to these guys ?

Comment: The echo version is not correct since the shortcode function should return a string which could be further processed by WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I hit upon a similar problem - I am regularly wanting to nest shortcodes where I couldn't/didn't want to edit the code I was nesting to call do_shortcode(). So I wrote a generic nesting shortcode routine. It allows you to nest shortcodes using {} instead of [], and requires that you use a couple of other escaped characters in the calls. It's below, but to use it in your example you would need to do:

```
[nest shortcode="wpfilebase" tag=file path='{page_title}' tpl=download-button /]
```

It also allows for parameters to be passed - in these cases you use ^ to represent spaces and ' to represent ". There are a couple of examples in the code comments.

I think this is better than wrapping the direct wpfilebase call in your code, just because if you want to change the wpfilebase call (adding parameters, etc) then you don't have to go back into functions.php and mess with the code, you can just do it in the page.

Hope this helps!

```
add_shortcode('nest', 'shortcode_nest');

function shortcode_nest($atts) {
    // Replace square brackets [] with curly braces {} to nest a shortcode call
    // Use hat ^ instead of spaces when adding parameters to nested calls
    // Use single quote ' instead of double quote " when adding parameters to nested calls
    // Call using [nest shortcode=originalshortcode param="in {getcountryshortcode}"]
    //    to generate [originalshortcode param="in United Kingdom"]
    // or [nest shortcode=originalshortcode content="hello!" param="in {getcountryshortcode}"]
    //    to generate [originalshortcode param="in United Kingdom"]hello![/originalshortcode]
    // or [nest shortcode=originalshortcode content="hello!" param="in {getcountryshortcode^id='94'}"]
    //    to generate [originalshortcode param="in Ireland"]hello![/originalshortcode]
    $shortcode = $atts["shortcode"];
    unset($atts["shortcode"]);
    $stratts = "";
    foreach ($atts as $key => $value) {
        $value = str_replace('{', '[', str_replace('}', ']', $value));
        $value = str_replace('^', ' ', $value);
        $value = str_replace('\'', '"', $value);
        $value = do_shortcode($value);
        if ($key == "content")
            $content = $value;
        else
            $stratts .= "$key='$value' ";
    }
    if (!isset($content))
        $fullcode = "[$shortcode $stratts]";
    else
        $fullcode = "[$shortcode $stratts]$content" . '[/' . $shortcode . ']';
    return do_shortcode($fullcode);
}
```